# how to pass return value fo a function to html div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to pass generated Random number from JS function to the html div, but its not able to pass it on,here is my code snippet

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="order" onclick="getRand()">orderId</button>
    <div id="order_id"></div>

    <script>
        var getRand = function () {
            var elem = Math.floor(Math.random() * 89999 + 10000);
            document.getElementById("order_id").innerHTML = elem.value;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `= elem.value` should be `= elem`

Comment: `elem` is a variable. Just do `innerHTML = elem`

Comment: Simply remove the `.value` in `innerHTML = elem.value`;

Comment: change elem.value to elem.

Answer (score 7):

Try with this: Working example :

```
 <html>
        <body>
        <head><h1>CRS</h1></head>
        <button id= "order" onclick="getRand()">orderId</button>
        <div id="order_id">ff</div>

         <script>
         var getRand = function() {
         var elem = Math.floor(Math.random()*89999+10000);
         document.getElementById("order_id").innerHTML = elem;
           };
         </script>
       </body>
      </html>
```

You just change `elem.value` to `elem`

Comment: @pPrasad_Joshi , you get your answer or not. May be this question is usefull for other stackoverflow visitor

Answer (score -3):

Check This Answers it is working good

```js
var getRand = function() {
     var elem = Math.floor(Math.random()*89999+10000);
     document.getElementById("order_id").innerHTML = elem;
       };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id= "order" onclick="getRand()">orderId</button>
    <div id="order_id">ff</div>
```

Comment: dont just copy paste others answer.